# Loading dataset using command line in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, argparse

I know that I can load the datasets in the pandas using the `read_csv` function of pandas as below

```
import pandas as pd

df = read_csv('/home/user/iris_dataset.csv', header=0)
df.head()
```

How can I load the same dataset using the command line arguments while executing the code ? I want to load the dataset to a data frame like `python3 example.py -D 'iris_dataset.csv'` while executing the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `sys.argv`

We can use `sys.argv` like so :

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys

  
df = pd.read_csv(f'/home/user/{sys.argv[1]}', header=0)
print(df.head())
```

We can call it using :

```sh
python example.py iris_dataset.csv
```

### Using `argparse`

Or we can use `argparse` :

```py
import argparse
import pandas as pd

my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
my_parser.add_argument('-D', action='store', type=str, required=True)
args = my_parser.parse_args()

df = pd.read_csv(f'/home/user/{args.D}', header=0)
print(df.head())
```

It works correctly using :

```sh
python example.py -D "iris_dataset.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I wanted to know if it can be done with argparse module as an alternative solution ?

Comment: Yes we can indeed, I updated the answer for you :) 
Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have a query - Here in this case cmd-line argument is of type `str` which is mentioned in `add_argument` function, for example, suppose I wanted to pass both float and int type in command line arg - what would be the type then in `add_argument` function ?

Comment: Glad it works ! As it does, don't hesitate to validate the answer and even upvote it ;)
To answer your additional query, you have two possibilities : as you expect a `int` or a `float`, you can set up `type=float` in `add_argument` as `int` is a subset of `float`. Or you can just remove the `type` parameter to accept whatever type you pass to it.

Comment: thanks ! Was wondering as to why you removed the old answer (one using sys.argv)- you can keep the old answer alongside with the new answer so that it can be helpful for others who visit this post. :) 
have upvoted your answer and marked your solution as accepted :)

Comment: I removed it as I wanted to answer your question very accurately, bespoke to your need. Indeed the first version was working as well, I just edited the answer, now both solutions are available.